# How to write a select statement in Wordpress file like "function.php"

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I tried this code in phpmyadmin before and it works fine

```
SELECT meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON post_id =564
WHERE meta_key =  'max_person';
```

But I don't know how to insert it in function.php

I insert this code and it works

```
<? PHP 
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $maxperson = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta inner join wp_posts ON post_id= %d WHERE meta_key = 'max_person'", $postid
        ) );
?>
```

But when I var_dumped `$maxperson` `var_dump ($maxperson);` it returns

`object(stdClass)#634 (1) { ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "5" }`
the result should be "5" i dont understand what that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it

`$value = (integer) $maxperson->meta_value;`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use custom query to get post by post ID or any other attributes.
go through WP documentation for detail.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
$args = array(
'p' => 42, // id of post
'meta_key' => 'max_person');
$my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thanks my code seems to be correct but I can't understand the output 
`object(stdClass)#634 (1) { ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "5" }`